# Implement Bootstrap Collapse with rails content_tag

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement BootStrap collapse with rails `content_tag`, see GIF below (I have BootStrap intergrated on the project)
[image: GIF of how Collapse works on Documentation]

Here's how mine currently looks like:

[image: My current output]

Edit:
I made some progress from Dave Kruz's answer, styling has taken effect, I just need help identifying what I'm missing to implement the collapse and expand.
[image: Styling taking effect]

Here's my code so far

```
c = content_tag(:button, "Show", class: "btn btn-primary", "data-toggle" => "collapse", "data-target" => "volunteerCollapse", type: "button")
v = volunteer_opportunity.users.map{ |user| user.volunteer_opportunities.map{ |vp| content_tag(:div, vp.title.to_s, class: 'collapse', id: "volunteerCollapse") }}.join(" ")
(c + v).html_safe
```

What am I missing that I should implement to have the collapse working well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling html_safe on v.

```
(c + v.html_safe)
```

Rails already understands that c is safe html because it is generated by content_tag. However, v is only a string - rails doesn't trust that it is html. When you concatenate them in your example, you get html with an escaped string added on to it.

Better yet, use raw which is pretty much the same but will not throw an error if v is nil.

```
 (c + raw(v))
```

And if security is a concern, you can go one better with sanitize.

```
(c + sanitize(v))
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

EDIT: To fix the expand, collapse on the Bootstrap side of this, you need to correct a couple things. First, your button should reference the target with a query selector syntax: data-target="#collapsibleID". Second, the collapsible content should be wrapped in an element with that id. You should not have an id appear more than once.

Here's how I'd revise your code:

```
    button = content_tag(:button, "Show", class: "btn btn-primary", "data-toggle" => "collapse", "data-target" => "#volunteerCollapse", type: "button")

    collapse_content = volunteer_opportunity.users.map{ |user| user.volunteer_opportunities.map{ |vp| content_tag(:div, vp.title.to_s) }}.join

    collapse_container = content_tag(:div, id: "volunteerCollapse", class: "collapse") do
      sanitize(collapse_content)
    end

    (button + collapse_container)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, at least I got the badge showing, now having the collapse behavior is what I'm hoping to get assistance on. I created a separate html page to see if it would work as it does on the docs, it does. So probably I need to figure out how it works using `content_tag`. But thank you for this!

Comment: I've added additional info to help with the Bootstrap side as well.